# Finite field-like structure with non-associative addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I have found the following structure which curiously satifies all the field axioms except for associativitiy of addition.

$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\ + & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 2 & 5 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 2\\
4 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 1\\
5 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\ \cdot & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 3\\
3 & 0 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 4\\
4 & 0 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 1\\
5 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{array}$

Has anyone seen this type of structure before? If so, could one provide a reference for its use or more information about them?

For the curious, the addition table was derived from a symmetric coloring of the edges of $K_6$, and the multiplication comes from the fact that coloring has a symmetry of order $5$, though I think it would be too much to write up the full details within the question.

Comment: Thanks remarkable...  after playing with a small program to verify, I was astounded to see distributivity hold.